# Xcode 4 assistant editor toggle key

Tags: xcode4, keyboard-shortcuts

In xcode4 you there's a key combo to show standard editor and one to show the assistant editor, but is there any way to use just one key combo to toggle between them? Similar to using command+option+up-arrow to cycle between related files.

Comment: I just found this question hoping to find the same thing.  Hopefully someone chimes up!

Comment: Have you considered 'Move Focus To Next Area' (Option + Command + .) and 'Move Focus to Precious Area' (Option + Command + >)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, to toggle between the Standard and Assistant editors, use Cmd+Option+Return

Comment: This shows it, but doesn't hide it for me in Xcode 7.2.1. Command + Enter hides it though

Answer (score 9):

To show Assistant Editor:

command shift Enter

To hide Assistant Editor (i.e. To show Standard Editor):

command Enter

[it thus hides the Assistant Editor]

Answer (score 4):

Customize the "Move Focus To Next Area" key binding under Preferences. (This automatically customizes the "Move Focus to Previous Area" binding by adding Shift to your binding.)

I changed mine to <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to follow the behavior of tab switching in Safari, Chrome, etc.

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back to the previous area feels awkward, but because it doesn't seem possible to customize "Move Focus to Previous Area" alone, there's no way to escape the Shift modifier.

For example, I would love to try this scheme:

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> // next
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> // previous

That would play nicely with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>{}</kbd> for switching between tabs; your fingers are probably already on <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> as you get your window contents set up with the default forward/back/related bindings.